# Need to configure Spartacus3 with Auth0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have to use Auth0 for the application and need to bypass Spartacus password login flow. I have gone through https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/session-management/#configuring-authorization-code-flow-or implicit-flow found that there is implicit flow to bypass login.
Tried with "authorizationserver/oauth/token" API hit manually and store token in local storage but getting other issues.
Can I know better approach to implement Auth0 in Spartacus and bypass password login flow.

Comment: What do you mean by bypassing password flow? Do you want to use implicit flow or something custom?
To avoid problems the easiest way is to use the whole implicit flow implemented (not doing everything from scratch).

Comment: @MarcinLasak Thanks for the response. "By-passing password flow" mean wana skip out of the box login flow. I wana use Auth0 for login application not Spartacus out of box login. can I know best way to do it. Can you provide any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Spartacus supports 3 flows with OAuth without any serious modifications required.

1. Password flow -> the default one. You login in spartacus form and the credentials are send to server and exchanged for access_token.
2. Implicit flow -> When you click login you are redirected to OAuth server login page. You put credentials there and after that you get redirected back to spartacus with access_token in on of the query params of the redirect url.
3. Authorization Code flow -> similar to Implicit flow, but in response you get `code` which then you need to send to oAuth server to exchange it for access_token.

To specify which flow you want to use you need to change the `responseType` config as mentioned in https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/session-management/#configuring-authorization-code-flow-or-implicit-flow

For Auth0 I would recommend going with Authorization Code Flow (as it's more secure than Implicit flow, especially with PKCE enabled).

Apart from the `responseType` you would need to set `baseUrl` in auth config to point it to Auth0 server (and I assume you have integration done in the backend that can verify tokens returned from Auth0). You might need to adjust few other config options as well, but you should be able to figure those out based on the problems you encounter.

Comment: I have tried giving response type in app.module.ts  in Imports
B2bStorefrontModule.withConfig({authentication: {OAuthLibConfig: {responseType: 'code',},}, })
In backoffice in OAuthClient section, For mobile android we added OAuth registered redirect URI as Auth0 token URL(https://{{auth0-domain}}/oauth/token) and gave grant type as Authorization_code. It is redirecting to "/authorizationserver/login.jsp"
I need to achive this Once userclick on custom login button user redirect to Auth0 login screen after successfull Auth0 login user need to redirect to Spartacus Authenticated dashboard page

Comment: In Auth0 portal we provided spartacus dashboard page url as redirect url. Can you please provide solution ?

Comment: Here is the flow that I had in mind:

Spartacus -> Auth0 -> Spartacus

I'm wondering why you try to go through the backoffice?

Comment: The flow is same as you thought[Spartacus(user clicks on login button) -> Auth0(Auth0 hosted login page) -> Spartacus(Authenticated dashboard page)]. We are not going through Backoffice.
As per your suggestion we tried changing OAuthClient in Backoffice(changed the redirect URL). Please let me know if this step is not required and any other thing need to be done to achieve the above flow

Comment: If you use Auth0 you don't need the OAuth client from backoffice. It is not needed in this case by spartacus.You should already achieve the desired flow. What problems do you still encounter?

Comment: Issue:
 As Hybris, required Oauth Authorization token call, Spartacus is calling it separately and storing in local Storage as mentioned in step 3 (called in app.component.ts) and then passing in every OCC API request header, As it is seperately called, whenever the token/session expires, it is re-directing us to the /login page which is not desirable.
Can you please suggest is this approcah is correct to get desired flow?